# journal specification for figures and figure captions

Tags: captions

I am submitting some work to a journal and the format of the article has to follow some specific guidelines. One of which is that following the main text, the figure captions are then required followed by the figures. How is it possible to separate the captions from the figures in latex?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem.  In particular, what do you mean by "the figure captions are then required followed by the figures"?

Comment: Following the main body of text, the journal requires each figure caption, so say if I have 3 figures, I should have three figure captions followed by the 3 figures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [endfloat](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/endfloat/) package

The documentation says

> **Why write this package?**
>
> Many journals require tables and figures to be separated from the text when you submit
>   those ugly double spaced copies. They also usually want a list of figures/tables before
>   these sections ...